# The Ages of Mathematician´s sons

Tags: puzzle

Two mathematicians meet and talk:

"Do you have a son?" asked the first mathematician.

"Yes I actually have three sons, and none of them are twins." answered the second mathematician.

"How old are they?" asked the first mathematician.

"The product of their age is equal to the month number at this moment." answered the second mathematician.

"It is not sufficient!" said the first mathematician.

"True, if you sum their ages next year it will again be equal to the month number at this moment." said the second mathematician.

**How old are his sons?** (I was not able to evaluate this mathematically!)

Comment: Hint 1 : The ages must be distinct (because there are no twins)

Comment: Hint 2 : No son can be older than $6$ because then the product would exceed $12$

Comment: I would like to point out that "there are no twins" does not necessarily guarantee that there are no two sons of the same age. However I posted my solution assuming there are no sons of the same age.

Comment: @Levent Strictly speaking, you are right.

Comment: Hint 3 : The solution is $(1,2,6)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3$ be the ages of the sons respectively. Observe that if the month is $1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11$ then there are no solutions using the fact that there are no twins. If the month is $6,8$ or $10$ then there is a unique solutions so just by the first information it would be possible to determine the ages. Hence the month must be December.

$12$ has two decompositions : $(1,2,6),(1,3,4)$ and the sum of their ages next year is $12$ in the former case and $11$ in the latter case.

Thus the solution is $(1,2,6)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your mathematically based solution!

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the solution if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: @Levent You have not considered that in a year all the three sons are one year older.

Comment: Oh god, I just added $1$ in the sums instead of $3$. Thank you very much for pointing out this stupid mistake. I'll edit.

Comment: @AdamPáltik You do not need mathematics of considerable level, if you apply some basic facts. You only have to look for duplicate products and check whether the claim with the sum fits. In fact, only $5$ triples are possible, considering the distinct numbers and that the product is not greater than $12$